# Show a screenshot as pdf download link

Tags: java, javascript, wordpress, pdf

Instead of showing a piece of text as pdf download link, I want to show a mini screenshot of the pdf as download link.

How should I do this (where to start)?
Example of a screenshot of my linkedin profile:

```
http://s.wordpress.com/mshots/v1/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Fedbras?w=115
```

This can then be included as background/image of a link in the front end.
How is this done?
This is from a web page, but the idea is to do the same for a generated pdf in the backend.
I am making backend calls through Javascript, and I have a Java backend, I am not using wordpress.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/index.html) and once the PDF file is uploaded use this method that loads the uploaded document from a path, takes the first page, converts it into an image and saves it into a path of your choice. Save this path in your DB record.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;

public class PDFUtil {

    public static void saveFirstPageThumbnail() throws IOException {
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load("C:\\testbook.pdf");
        List<PDPage> pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
        PDPage page = pages.get(0); //first one
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = page.convertToImage();
        File outputFile = new File( "C:\\image.jpg");
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", outputFile);
    }

}
```

Later on when you're required to print links just return the path of your created image in the callback and form your link in normal html:

```
<a href="path/to/document.pdf"><img src="path/to/image.jpg" /></a>
```

and here's the library dependency if you're using maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, if you have the PDF and the screenshot image, you'd just write

```
<a href="yourPDFlink.pdf"><img src="http://s.wordpress.com/mshots/v1/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Fedbras?w=115" alt="Name of your PDF"/></a>
```

Comment: I am not using wordpress and want to know how to create the screenshot in my backend.

Comment: The link was taken right from your example.  It can be any link.  Wordpress or not.

Comment: And how does this "any link" creates the requested image ? That is the question....

Comment: You asked how to make the link, not how to make the image.

Answer (score 0):

Under ABCPdf .NET you would just write:

```
Doc doc = new Doc();
doc.Read(@"c:\mydoc.pdf");
doc.Rendering.Save(@"c:\mydoc.jpg");
```

Pretty simple eh?

Please note that the internals PDF rendering are pretty complex and many solutions skip important features such as transparency groups and blends.

So when selecting your rendering solution do consider where your documents come from.

If they come from a uniform source you probably don't need to worry too much about things going wrong. If it works for one it will probaby work for all.

However if your documents come from a real world source you need to ensure that your rendering solution is full featured so that it can cope with all documents rather than just common ones.

My replies may feature concepts based around ABCpdf .NET. It's what I work on - it's what I know. :-)